# Why the logout button is not navigating to login page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux, react-router

I am learning firebase. I have a button **log out**. When I am clicking on the button it is not navigating to **login** page.

I have set routing with **user.emailVerified** value.

**Nav.jsx**

```
import { getAuth, signOut } from 'firebase/auth';
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { setLogOut } from '../redux/slice';

const Nav = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const auth = getAuth();
  const dispatch = useDispatch()


  const logOutHandler = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(setLogOut())
        navigate('/login', { replace: true });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light ">
      <div className="container">
        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
          Navbar
        </Link>
        <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
          Home
        </Link>
        <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary" onClick={logOutHandler}>
          Log Out
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';
import EmailVerify from './pages/EmailVerify';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';

const App = () => {
  const [verified, setverified] = useState();

  // get user information
  const auth = getAuth();
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if (user) {
      setverified(user.emailVerified);
    } else {
      // User is signed out
      // ...
    }
  });

  let routes;
  if (verified) {
    routes = (
      <>
        <Nav />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    routes = (
      <>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
          <Route path="/email-verify" element={<EmailVerify />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/login" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </>
    );
  }

  return <>{routes}</>;
};

export default App;
```

**redux**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';

const initialState = {
  email: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('email')),
  isLoggedIn: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedInStatus')),
};

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'slice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLogInValue: (state, action) => {
      localStorage.setItem('email', JSON.stringify(action.payload));
      localStorage.setItem('loggedInStatus', JSON.stringify(true));

      state.email = action.payload;
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
    },
    setLogOut: state => {
      localStorage.setItem('email', null);
      localStorage.setItem('loggedInStatus', false);

      state.email = null;
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
    },
  },
});

export const { setLogInValue, setLogOut } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

I am wanting to go **login** page when I click on **log out** button because when I am clicking on **logout** it is user is null then. But why not navigating to **login** page? How can I do that?

Comment: Where does it navigate? Is there any console error? What is in verified variable on render after logout? I think onAuthStateChanged should be in "didMount" hook

Comment: I placed onAuthStateChanged inside the useEffect hook but nothing changed. There is not console error. After click on logout button if I refresh the page then it goes to login page.

Comment: Try to put the navigate to login to onAuthStateChanged, when there is no user. Please update the code.

Comment: I have added `setverified(false)` to the `onAuthStateChanged` on `App.jsx` and it is working as I wanted.

Comment: It doesn't appear the code ever invalidates a user, the `verified` state doesn't get set to a falsey value. Also, what is the authentication source of truth? You've a firebase `onAuthStateChanged` handler, local `verified` component state, stuff in Redux, ***and*** values in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I have added `setverified(false)` on `else` condition of the `onAuthStateChanged` on `App.jsx` and it is working as I wanted.

**Updated portion:**

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if (user) {
      setverified(user.emailVerified);
    } else {
      setverified(false); // updated line
    }
  });
```